# Powershell script in columns instead of rows

Tags: powershell, wmi

I was trying to write a script which would use a text file with hostnames and needs to generate a file with the extra data. I can only manage to get it in rows instead of columns:

```
Model: 
Bios Version: 
TPM OEM Ver: 
User logged In:
```

I would also like to get the emailaddress from the logged on user. I was thinking to use get-aduser. Could I add another foreach after the current code, using the column with the usernames? How would I do this? 
All help is greatly appreciated!

My code is:

```
$output = foreach ($hostname in Get-Content C:\temp\hostnames.txt)
{
$computerinfo = get-ciminstance -computername $hostname Win32_ComputerSystem
$computerBIOS = get-ciminstance -computername $hostname Win32_BIOS
$tpm = Get-ciminstance -class Win32_Tpm -namespace root\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftTpm -ComputerName $hostname
"Hostname: " + $computerinfo.name
"Model: " + $computerinfo.Model 
"Bios Version: " + $computerBIOS.smbiosbiosversion
"TPM OEM Ver: " + $tpm.ManufacturerVersion
"User logged In: " + $computerinfo.UserName
} 
$output | out-file 'C:\Temp\hostnames3.txt' -append
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the CSV file format instead of plain text for structured data. That makes it easier to use them for further steps if needed.

```
$output = 
foreach ($hostname in Get-Content C:\temp\hostnames.txt) {
    $computerinfo = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $hostname -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem
    $computerBIOS = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $hostname -ClassName Win32_BIOS
    $tpm = Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftTpm -ComputerName $hostname -ClassName Win32_Tpm
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Hostname       = $computerinfo.name
        Model          = $computerinfo.Model
        Bios_Version   = $computerBIOS.smbiosbiosversion
        TPM_OEM_Ver    = $tpm.ManufacturerVersion
        User_logged_In = $computerinfo.UserName
    }
} 
$output | 
    Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\hostnames3.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

In my experience the `UserName` property of the CIM-Class `Win32_ComputerSystem` is unreliable to determine the logged on user. I usually use good old `quser.exe` like this:

```
$UserQuery = ( C:\Windows\System32\quser.exe /server:$hostname 2> null)
        if ($UserQuery) {
            $UserQuery[1].Trim() -match "^(\S+)\s+.*((\d{2}\.){2}\d{4}\s+\d{2}:\d{2})" | Out-Null
            $LoggedOnUser = $Matches[1]
            $LogonTime = Get-Date -Date $Matches[2]
        }
```

Then you can use `$LoggedOnUser` and `$LogonTime` to include it in your output object if you like.

Of course you can include a additional AD query for more information about the logged on user.